# find all the answers of these equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

find all the answers of these equations:

$x_{1} + x_{2} = x_{3} ^2$

$x_{2} + x_{3} = x_{4} ^2$

$x_{3} + x_{4} = x_{5} ^2$

$x_{4} + x_{5} = x_{1} ^2$

$x_{5} + x_{1} = x_{2} ^2$

**My attempt**:By summing all equations we can easily find that one answer is that all of them are zero but what about other answers?

In the hint of the book is written that first show $x_1=x_5$.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$? Are they real numbers? Or are they integers?

Comment: It's known all are integers?

Comment: There is no imformation that means it's real solutions.

Comment: Then why the tag ?

Comment: Is this not a system of 10 variables and 5 equations?

Comment: @ user160110 there are $5$ variables.

Comment: @user160110 There are only $5$ variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $x_5$.

Comment: I am looking at the first equations as $x_1+x_2+0x_3+0x_4 +0x_5+0x_1^2+0x_2^2-x_3^2+0x_4^2+0x_5^2=0$

Comment: @user160110 then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full fledged answer but maybe you or someone else can take what I have worked on and turn it into an answer.

Given $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y$ you can determine $x_3,x_4,$ and $x_5$ by simply using three out of the 5 equations to define them namely

1. $x_3=\sqrt{x+y}$ (Using the first equation)
2. $x_5=y^2-x$      (Using the last equation)
3. $x_4=x^2+x-y^2$  (Using the fourth equation)

Given that this is true it follows that the 2nd and 3rd equation only serve as checks for your solutions. So you can rewrite them in terms of x and y, and gain two equalities.

(1).   $x_2+x_3=x_4^2$ gets rewritten as $y+\sqrt{x+y}=(x^2+x-y^2)^2$

(2).  $x_3+x_4=x_5^2$ gets rewritten as $\sqrt{x+y}+x^2+x-y^2=(y^2-x)^2$

Simplifying this and subtracting the two equations will give you a quadratic in terms of y.

$y+\sqrt{x+y}=x^4+x^2+y^4-2xy^2+2x^3-2x^2y^2$  (Equation 1)

$-(\sqrt{x+y}+x^2+x-y^2=y^4-2xy^2+x^2)$    (-Equation 2)

---

$y-x^2-x+y^2=x^4+2x^3-2x^2y^2$(New Equation=Equation 1- Equation 2)

$(2x^2+1)y^2+y-(x^4+2x^3+x^2+x)=0$(Simplified)

Which will give you a 2 possible solutions for $y$ given an x. Problem is it is possible that both solutions are Extraneous(crops up from the use of elimination).

$\bar{y}(x)=y_{solution}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4(2x^2+1)(x^4+2x^3+x^2+x)}}{2(2x^2+1)}$

This can be avoided by simply plugging the solutions into one of the prior equations (1) or (2) and verifying that it is also a solution there. Problem is the calculation and analysis is so messy at this point that, that verifying.

Verify that $\bar{y}(x)+\sqrt{x+\bar{y}(x)}=(x^2+x-(\bar{y}(x))^2)^2$ implies that $x=2$ or $x=0$(Pain in the ass right?)

Anyways at least it's down to one variable right?(Hell you might even be able to use some calculus on that mug.)

Answer (score 1):

A non-trivial solution is given by
$$
(x_1,\ldots ,x_5)=(2,2,2,2,2).
$$

Edit: The system has $32$ complex solutions, two of them are real, even integral, namely $(0,0,0,0,0)$ and $(2,2,2,2,2)$. I used elimination and reduced the system to two equations in $x_1$ and $x_2$, but there will be more elegant solutions.

Comment: I want a solution to show there is only two solutions.It's easy to find out the answers.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: You seem to be engaged in a significant amount of goalpost-moving here. When you asked your question you just showed the equations, without further. Now you're simply changing the task, saying that "it's easy to find" Dietrich's solution, but _there was no hint of that in your question as posted_. Shame on you!

Comment: @Henning Makholm In the question I wrote down that find (all) the answers of this equation.If you think there is no other solutions You should simply prove it.But I don't gave any downvotes.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: In your question you wrote that you knew about the solution where all the unknowns are zero. You wrote **not any word** about knowing any other solution.  So either you're lying NOW when you say you already knew about Dietrich's solution, or you were deliberately concealing information about the question that was known to you when you asked. Which is it?

Comment: @Henning Makholm None of them!I don't knew the answers befor I check the hints in the end.I also don't knew them after that inthe hint is written prove that $x_1=x_5=2or0$ That I don't knew the answers when I posted the comment.I just wrote it is easy to find out not I found them;)